# Sci-Fi book about a colony ship

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a book I read in the early 1980s.  A large colony ship is heading to another planet.

All I can remember is a couple quotes and situations:

1. The captain (or some authority figure on the ship) says "there are two tough guys on this ship, and I'm both of them"
2. One of the passengers is a very sexy sixteen-year old - somebody wonders "If she's like this at sixteen, what could the future hold?"
3. They're exploring a planet and a plant seems to speak to one of the scientists.  "Intellegent?!" he marvels.  The plant eats him.  It's not an intellegent life-form, it turns out it only mimics sounds that it hears.

Not much to go on, I admit.  I read it in the early 80s, and if I remember right it was a fairly long book - maybe 400 or 500 pages.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 15):

*[Star Colony](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Star_Colony/IqiTCwAAQBAJ)* by Keith Laumer.

> Coming in fast and low, the huge ship made planetfall. Three years out from Terra, the colony ship Omega had reached her destination, and the crew began to off-load the cargo and passengers.
>
> Then the ship vanished.
>
> Against the vast panorama of an unexplored universe, Keith Laumer sets this first volume of the history of the world called Colmar - mankind's first venture among the stars.

From [a Google Books search](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Star_Colony/IqiTCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22two%20tough%20guys%22%20colony%20ship&pg=PT11&printsec=frontcover) for `"two tough guys" colony ship`:

> “There's only two tough guys aboard this tub,” he stated, “and I'm both of 'em. Dismissed,”

....

> Tey was unpreparted for the impact of the face-to-face confrontation with the ravishing youth, beauty, and above all, feminimity of Renee, who in turn seemed almost drab in contrast with the full-blooming radiance of the prime young beauty beside her, whom Tey barely recognized as Sugar. *If she's like this at almost sixteen,* his dazed mind wondered, *what can the future hold?*

Comment: That's the book! Thanks very much FuzzyBoots! I'd accept your answer and vote, but I can't figure out how. (Maybe the option isn't available because I enrolled as a new user with a new user-name since I asked the question..??) Anyway, thanks much!

Comment: @WeakyReader You can follow the instructions here to [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and then you'll be able to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.